# Can I make an invisible Floating Div over navigation background image to make header clickable, wordpress toolbox theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://66.147.244.96/~safeedu2/wordpress/

Hello, I now have a clickable box (to the left) in the white area that will link to my homepage, but I want it to float on top of the "book logo", so it's not a white strip at the top of my design. Is this possible? Here is my new CSS:

```
/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#site-title {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 160px;
    width: 130px;
}

#site-title a {
    display: block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

#site-description {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand the question. could you share some code or cerate a fiddle? it is possible. try  to set the position (position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:orange;z-index:99999;)now you should see an orange div on your site which is clickable.. maybe change top,left, width, height and remove the background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should read [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)**

You have two problems:

- It's useless to use a huge `z-index` if that element belongs to an stacking context below another.
- If you want an empty element to be visible, you must give them dimensions (e.g. `height: 100%;width: 100%;`) and be aware that if it is an inline element by default, you also need `display: block;` (or `inline-block`), or it will ignore the dimensions.

You can add

```
#site-title {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 6; /* because #access has z-index:5 */
}

#site-title a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely read up on zindex. Right now in Wordpress I do not have a "site title" or "header image" because I wanted it to be in my background img in my navigation (which is the book image and the words "somali and american fund for education". Should I add another div in the header.php file in order to make a clickable area? I have attached that code.

Comment: Hello, if you update my link I now have a clickable box that is the same width and height as my "book logo" but it is floating above it. Can this be fixed so it lays on top of the book? Thank you! Leah

Comment: @leahdesigns I think you should: 1) Cut your logo image, deleting the text and leaving the book. 2) Include that image using `<img>` instead of `background-image`. 3) Add that `<img>` inside an anchor. 4) Include *Somali and americand fund for education* as text, not image

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I was hoping there was an easier workaround, but that should do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Oriol, I completed your suggestion but now I have a weird dark grey thin box below the clickable book logo. Do you think that had anything to do with me adding that new Div? Thank you!

Comment: I have! Thank you so much for your help today!